# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'machine_name' with CE 3.2 SQL Server

Tags: corda

I'm trying to launch a `Corda Enterprise 3.2` node with a Microsoft SQL Server 2017 database and I get this error at startup:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'machine_name'.

It was working fine with `CE 3.1`.

Here is an extract from my `node.conf`

```
"dataSourceProperties" : {
    "dataSource" : {
    "user":"<username>",
            "password":"<password>",
            "url" : "jdbc:sqlserver://<HOST>:<PORT>;encrypt=false;databaseName=corda"
    },
    "dataSourceClassName" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource"
},
"database" : {
    "runMigration" : true,
    "schema" : "dbo",
    "transactionIsolationLevel" : "READ_COMMITTED"
},
```

I use `mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar` as JDBC driver

Answer (score 1):

It was a case sensitive DB configuration issue.
Solved with this sql command :

`USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE corda
COLLATE French_CI_AS ;
GO`

Old value was was : `French_CS_AS`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to run the database migration tool to upgrade from 3.1 to 3.2. Do you have that Jar file already? If this is a test environment and you don't care about application data in the vault you can always drop/recreate the corda database. Restarting 3.2 will then build the necessary tables. If you need to preserve data then database migration tool is the way to go.

https://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html?highlight=migration

https://docs.corda.r3.com/database-management.html?highlight=migration#migration-tool

Comment: This is a brand new CE 3.2 database.
I did the migration :
`java -jar corda-tools-database-manager-3.2.jar --base-directory ~/corda/node --dry-run`
and `java  -jar corda-tools-database-manager-3.2.jar --base-directory ~/corda/node --execute-migration`
And the tables were created as exepected

Comment: There is now an open issue on the Corda JIRA : https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-2281

Comment: Hi Remi - can you drop and recreate the database (don't run the migration tool) and restart the node with 3.2 ensuring you have the following section in node.conf:                                                                                                    "database" : {
        "runMigration" : "true",
        "schema" : "dbo",
        "transactionIsolationLevel" : "READ_COMMITTED"
    },

Comment: This should create all of the 3.2 tables needed from scratch.